# How to remove Ruby Gems which have failed to install properly

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a prescribed way to "clean up" Ruby Gems which have native extensions that have failed to build. There are directories/files left in the gems directory, however *gem list --local* does not list them as being installed.
e.g. sqlite3-ruby, linecache, mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no predefined way.
The good news is that with 1.9.2, it should not count these as gems anymore (I assume that you're on 1.9.1)?

Comment: Yes, I'd noticed on 1.9.2 that they aren't listed by the gem list --local command. I'm using 1.8.7, 1.9.1 and 1.9.2. It isn't a problem as such, but would be nice to be able to remove them since they aren't functional. I resorted to manually deleting the folders, which hasn't seemed to break anything.

Comment: I guess the only way then would be to compare the output of "gem list" with the contents of your gem dirs.

You could write a plugin that would do this automagically for you, though, probably.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can remove a specific version of the gem:

```
gem uninstall (gem name here) --version (version number here)
```

to remove gems from a specific version and back use:

```
gem uninstall (gem name here) --version '<(version number here)'
```

this will remove all lesser versions.